# Missing ecto association between models

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm following the "Programming Phoenix" book by Chris McCord and in Chapter 6, a relationship is created between a `User` and a `Video`.

When trying to run it with `mix phoenix.server`, the following error shows up:

```
Request: GET /manage/videos
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) schema Rumbl.User does not have association :videos
        (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:121: Ecto.Association.association_from_schema!/2
```

Going over the book's errata, there's a comment from another user mentioning that this happens because the logged in user does not have any videos associated with them.

Below is the content of `user.ex`

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do
    use Rumbl.Web, :model

    schema "users" do
        field :name, :string
        field :username, :string
        field :password, :string, virtual: true
        field :password_hash, :string

        timestamps
    end

    def changeset(user, params \\ :empty) do
        user
        |> cast(params, ~w(name username), [])
        |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
    end

    def registration_changeset(user, params) do
        user
        |> changeset(params)
        |> cast(params, ~w(password), [])
        |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
        |> put_pass_hash()
    end

    def put_pass_hash(changeset) do
        case changeset do
            %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
                put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
                _-> changeset
        end
    end
end
```

How can I gracefully handle this case?

Comment: That comment sounds incorrect. Can you please post the contents of `web/models/user.ex`? There's probably a missing `has_many :videos, ...`.

Comment: Sure, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to add `has_many :videos, Rumbl.Video` inside `schema "users"` in `web/models/user.ex`:

```
schema "users" do
  # ...
  has_many :videos, Rumbl.Video
  # ...
end
```

as mentioned in Chapter 6 (page 100 of the p1_0 PDF) and in [this snippet](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/phoenix/code/relationships/listings/rumbl/web/models/user.change1.ex).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reference was not **plural**. Was getting the same error.

*Wrong*

```
has_many :video, Rumbl.Video
```

*Correct*

```
has_many :videos, Rumbl.Video
```